# How to Pass Two Values From PHP to Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Can you please let me know how I can pass Two Values from PHP file into a jQuery Ajax script. What I have is a Ajax call as:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var req = $.ajax({
                url: 'captcha.php',
            });
            req.done(function(data){
                alert(data);
        })
    });
</script>
```

and my PHP (captcha.php) is like:

```
<?php
  $number1 = rand(1,9);
  $number2 = rand(1,9);
  $sum = $number1 + $number2;
  echo $number1;
?>
```

as you can see currently I am able to pass the value of the `$number1` but I need to have both values(`$number1` and `$number2`). Can you please let me know how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of sending (invalid) HTML to the client, use a structured data format, such as JSON.

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $data = Array($number1, $number2);
    print json_encode($data);
    exit;
```

In the JavaScript, jQuery will now populate `data` with an array.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, can you please let me know why are you using the header() function here?

Comment: @Suffii — Because PHP, by default, will claim that the output is HTML. Since this code outputs JSON, not HTML, that would be wrong. If the server tells the browser that the content is HTML, then jQuery will try to parse it as HTML instead of as JSON which is, obviously, undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make an array containing variables to return and json_encode it to parse it in JS?

```
echo json_encode(array($number1, $number2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array out of your values:

```
$array = array($number1, $number2);
```

Then parse it to json

```
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Then echo out the $json and you have multiple variables in your js!

Comment: Thanks KhorneHoly, can please also let me know how I can decode the $json on js part? thanks

Comment: @Suffii — The best way is to set the correct content-type header, as per my answer, and then jQuery will do it automatically.

Comment: @Suffii the header part from Quentin is good, adapt that from him. In your JS your `data` will be a simple array which you can use then. No decoding needed :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var req = $.ajax({
                url: 'captcha.php',
            });
            req.done(function(data){
               data = data.split(",");
               //Number 1
               alert(data[0]);
               //Number 2
               alert(data[1]);
        })
    });
</script>

<?php
  $number1 = rand(1,9);
  $number2 = rand(1,9);
  $sum = $number1 + $number2;
  echo $number1 .",". $number2;
?>
```

All this does is tells the php script to echo Number1,Number2 and then the javascript splits this string into an array from the ,

Answer (score -1):

**First Way**
You can concatenate the two values seperating them by a special character like `'_'` like this

PHP

```
echo $number1 . '_' . $number2;
```

And then do like this in javascript

```
data = data.split('_'); // get an array with the two values
```

**Second way**
You can encode as JSON in php and do a json ajax request

PHP

```
$result = array($number1, $number2);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Javascript

```
$.getJSON('captcha.php',function(data){
    console.log(data); //
});
```